# Chart Interaction for multiple data sources

Tags: looker-studio

I have three charts on my report. A geomap, table 1 and table 2. For Geomap and Table 1 the data source is DB1 and for table 2 data source is DB2. DB1 has the information PID (Primary Key), Name, City, Province where as DB2 has PID, Title, Current Organization, City and Current status.

I am trying to add a chart interaction filter so I can filter values using a click for all three charts. However, for chart 2, it doesnt change when I click the name on Table 1. Is there a way I can use PID such that when I click something on Table 1 it uses PID, finds that PID in DB2 and displays that information in table 2?

It may be a basic question and my experience with data studio is only 2 days. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your 2 data sources can be joined on PID. I suggest creating a 'blended data' and use it for all 3 charts/tables.

An alternative is to select all the filter and 3 charts/tables then right-click -> `Group`.